# Change CSS Properties From Wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, admin, panel

I created an options page. My options page contains some fields for inputting text, uploading images, and for uploading Google Adsense Ads for my theme. But now I'm adding a color picker for choosing a custom color for my background header. This is my code; it is responsible for the header background color.

```
$YPE_options = get_option( 'YPE_header_option_name' );
$YPE_options['YPE_header_bg'];
```

and this is my header HTML Markup Code

```
<header id="single-header" class="jumbotron">
<div class="container text-center">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
        </a>
    <div>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added some properties to `jumbotron` class in my `style.css` file below

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: url('../img/slideshow-img/slide1.jpg')  top no-repeat;
    padding: 24px 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px #777;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px #777;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px #777;
}
```

I added `url('../img/slideshow-img/slide1.jpg')  top no-repeat` property as background image for my header.

I want say `if isset($YPE_options['YPE_header_bg'])` show my color instead of my image else show me the image as background

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action, and you should, you can do like this...

In your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_css' );

function custom_css() {

    $YPE_options = get_option( 'YPE_header_option_name' );


    if( isset( $YPE_options['YPE_header_bg'] ) ) {
        printf(
            '<style type="text/css"> .jumbotron { background: %s; }</style>',
            $YPE_options['YPE_header_bg'] 
        );
    }

}
```

It'll override your style.css

PS: I didn't test the code, but I think it's all ok and it should work.

**Update:**

- Forgot to close isset() ( Already closed now )

Comment: thank you for your reply but i can't use this function within my header.php or in my options.php page

Comment: Can I ask you why? And you should not put this in your header, it should be in your functions.php what is suposed to be in your header is the wp_head(); action

Comment: are the wordpress developers use this way to upload and retrieve css data from admin panel to theme?

Comment: If you check the wp_head() url, in the post, there is a example, almost like mine, but not getting the data from get_option(), just a normal inline css. It's the first example.

Comment: i'm beginner in Wordpress but when i see some themes in themeforest contain the admin panel within the admin panel i see huge number of css fields and properties but i can't know how developers retrieve this properties to the theme

Comment: For a lot of customization you could change the if statement and  the printf function. But for one customization and just for your background, that function should work fine. If you need more you have to re-factor the code.

Comment: If i create the text field in my options page and this is the value of the field $YPE_options['YPE_header_margin'] for changing the margin in jumbotron class how can do it? i add another if statement for changing margin or i cant do this within your first if statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54889/discussion-between-marcos-rodrigues-and-shwan-namiq).

Answer (score 0):

if i read your question right.

one option, two steps:

step one) change class of A element based on isset($YPE_options['YPE_header_bg'])
this allows you to set a background color.

step two) show the image only if NOT isset($YPE_options['YPE_header_bg'])

oops: you have a background image in css for jumbotron (so it looks from your mark up). so you may want to change that class as well, to display background image based on your isset($YPE_options['YPE_header_bg'])

Comment: i can use the if statement but i can't know how and when use it i want when user want change background from image to color in my admin panel automatically show the color instead the image background

Comment: yes i want change only background property in jumbotron class